# how to add an element on top of another element that have been dynamically created in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a button allowing to display more fields in order to get supplementary information about a user(his address & his email).
well, when I click on the button it adds the fields, the trouble is with their positions, I want it to be above the button not below it

[image]

here is the code

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function addUser() {
      let position2 = document.getElementById("position2");

      var name = document.createElement("label");
      position2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("name"));

      var inputName = document.createElement("input");
      inputName.setAttribute("type", "text");
      position2.appendChild(inputName);

      var retuurn = document.createElement("br");
      position2.appendChild(retuurn);


      var btn = document.createElement("input");
      btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
      btn.setAttribute("value", "add informations");
      btn.setAttribute("onclick", "showMore()");
      position2.appendChild(btn);
      position2.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      position2.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      position2.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }



    function showMore() {
      var adress = document.createElement("label");
      position2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("adress"));

      var inputAdress = document.createElement("input");
      inputAdress.setAttribute("type", "text");
      position2.appendChild(inputAdress);
      var retuurn = document.createElement("br");
      position2.appendChild(retuurn);

      var email = document.createElement("label");
      position2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("email"));

      var inputEmail = document.createElement("input");
      inputEmail.setAttribute("type", "text");
      position2.appendChild(inputEmail);

      var retuurn = document.createElement("br");
      position2.appendChild(retuurn);
      var retuurn = document.createElement("br");
      position2.appendChild(retuurn);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form">

    <div id="position2"></div>

    <button type="button" onclick="addUser()"> click to add user </button> <br><br>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your script is telling something else.

Comment: what does it tell ?

Comment: you are making this complex for your self why don't you create tags in html and show hide them on click event?

Comment: how ? can u write me the code

Comment: yeah sure I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) instead of `appendChild`. It takes a second argument, which in your case should be the button element.

In order to get a reference to the button, I would associate the button's click handler via script, not via the `onclick` attribute. Then the handler will get the event object, which has the button in its `target` property.

See below for the changes:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function addUser() {
      let position2 = document.getElementById("position2");

      var name = document.createElement("label");
      position2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("name"));

      var inputName = document.createElement("input");
      inputName.setAttribute("type", "text");
      position2.appendChild(inputName);

      var retuurn = document.createElement("br");
      position2.appendChild(retuurn);


      var btn = document.createElement("input");
      btn.setAttribute("type", "button");
      btn.setAttribute("value", "add informations");
      btn.onclick = showMore; // <----
      position2.appendChild(btn);
      position2.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      position2.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      position2.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }



    function showMore(e) { // <--- argument
      var btn = e.target; // <--- get button
      var adress = document.createElement("label");
      // call insertBefore with second argument
      position2.insertBefore(document.createTextNode("adress"), btn);

      var inputAdress = document.createElement("input");
      inputAdress.setAttribute("type", "text");
      position2.insertBefore(inputAdress, btn);
      var retuurn = document.createElement("br");
      position2.insertBefore(retuurn, btn);

      var email = document.createElement("label");
      position2.insertBefore(document.createTextNode("email"), btn);

      var inputEmail = document.createElement("input");
      inputEmail.setAttribute("type", "text");
      position2.insertBefore(inputEmail, btn);

      var retuurn = document.createElement("br");
      position2.insertBefore(retuurn, btn);
      var retuurn = document.createElement("br");
      position2.insertBefore(retuurn, btn);

      btn.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form">

    <div id="position2"></div>

    <button type="button" onclick="addUser()"> click to add user </button> <br><br>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: good job ! what if I want to disable the button afterwards the first add ?

Comment: You can give it a disabled attribute. Added to the answer.